# Possible GCC Bug: Long arguments shortened when linking a library to project. C\C++

Tags: c, windows, gcc, codeblocks

I'm not sure if this is a bug or I'm just missing something.  I've tried this with MinGW's gcc version 4.8.1 (tdm-2) from both Code::Blocks and CodeLite, and with another library, (SFML).  Whenever I link a library to my program, the arguments are read differently than when I directly add the library to my program.  It's a custom library that I wrote and it's only one file big; I added it to the project to quickly work out some bugs in the library.  When the library is directly compiled into the project, everything works fine.  When I link the library to the project, long arguments get cut short.  I've boiled it down to this snippet of code:

```
unsigned int count = 0; count2 = 0;
char         charbuffer[128] = {0};
do
  {
    printf("\nBefore Count: %3d, Count2: %3d, Addthem: %3d, Next: %02X", count, count2, count+count2, argv[5][count+count2]);
    for(count = 0; argv[5][count+count2] != 0 && count < 128; ++count)
      charbuffer[count] = argv[5][count+count2];
    count2 += count;
    printf("\nAfter  Count: %3d, Count2: %3d, Addthem: %3d, Next: %02X", count, count2, count+count2, argv[5][count+count2]);
  }
while(argv[5][count+count2] != 0);
```

The argument is 344 bytes long, (I mashed on the keyboard to get it) and when the library is directly in the program, it loops 4 times, which is what I want.  When I remove the file and link the library, it only runs 2 times.  When I add a printf("%s", argv[5]); it always prints out the full argument, and I have a counter before that to check the length of the argument, so I know it's being sent to the program properly; and I always use the same argument for each run.

```
Output when in project:  
Before Count:   0, Count2:   0, Addthem:   0, Next: 32
After  Count: 128, Count2: 128, Addthem: 256, Next: 79
Before Count: 128, Count2: 128, Addthem: 256, Next: 79
After  Count: 128, Count2: 256, Addthem: 384, Next: 6D
Before Count: 128, Count2: 256, Addthem: 384, Next: 6D
After  Count:  88, Count2: 344, Addthem: 432, Next: 4E
Before Count:  88, Count2: 344, Addthem: 432, Next: 4E
After  Count:   0, Count2: 344, Addthem: 344, Next: 00
```

---

```
Output when linked:  
Before Count:   0, Count2:   0, Addthem:   0, Next: 32
After  Count: 128, Count2: 128, Addthem: 256, Next: 79
Before Count: 128, Count2: 128, Addthem: 256, Next: 79
After  Count: 128, Count2: 256, Addthem: 384, Next: 00
```

From what I can tell, it looks like 334 bytes is the limit for an argument when linking before it has a problem.  The Linux GCC does not seem to be affected by this bug.  When I compile it as a 64 bit app, with or without linking, the bug seems to occur.  The files are not changed when this issue occurs.  At least one part of the library must be used.

Can anyone confirm if this is a bug?  Should I post anything else?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bug:
You should zero `count` before evaluating `while(argv[5][count+count2] != 0);`.

If you don't do so, you'll access the `argv` array out of bounds which can be different on every build.

```
    ...
    count2 += count;
    printf("\nAfter  Count: %3d, Count2: %3d, Addthem: %3d, Next: %02X", count, count2, count+count2, argv[5][count+count2]);
    count = 0; // add this
  }
while(argv[5][count+count2] != 0);
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked.  Here's the thing though, why did simply linking a library to the program change how it was calculating?  It's the same code.

Comment: Just dumb luck. The result could have been identical and you wouldn't have found the bug...